# How do you use web sockets in ColdFusion with a non-ColdFusion front-end?

Tags: websocket, coldfusion

**Situation**

We are using a ColdFusion Server for API calls only. We are extending it to include web sockets.

Including web sockets with ColdFusion is fairly simplistic if you use ColdFusion Markup for your website which we are not, which leads to the question.

**Question**

How do you establish and use web sockets in ColdFusion when you are not using ColdFusion in your front-end.

Comment: With JavaScript. [Why not check a basic tutorial?](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Comment: I have done this with nodejs with no issue what so ever. However, ColdFusion is ... opinionated.